# Ternary relationships with Javascript ORM

Tags: sql, orm, sequelize.js, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I've been having trouble finding any examples or tutorials about how to create ternary relationships with a Javascript library like Sequelize or knex/Bookshelf.

Is there a way to define such an associative entity? A specific example is a mechanical turk `Assignments` relation that is an associative entity for 3 relations: `Workers`, `Tasks` and `Images`.

Comment: I might have just answered my own question (at least with `knex`). Here's a migration that would do the same thing as SQL:

exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.createTable('Assignments', (table) => {
    table.integer('Worker_id').unsigned().references('workers.id').primary();
    table.integer('Tasks_id').unsigned().references('tasks.id').primary();
    table.integer('Images_id').unsigned().references('images.id').primary();
    ...
  })
};
exports.down = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.dropTable('Assignments');
};

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask